# i915 vs i915_bpo

Tags: grub2, 16.04, intel-graphics, i915

At work I received 3 identical desktop with Skylake CPU and i915 integrated graphic chipset.
Both first and second desktop are working with the i915_bpo driver and both accepted a dual displays.

The last one doesn't boot without the 'nomodeset' parameter in grub2 and it tries to load both i915 and i915_bpo drivers.

They are few differences on how the kernel detects them.

The first desktop:

```
$ sudo lshw -c display

*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics                                                                                                                                                                                     
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation                                                                                                                                                                                             
       identifiant matériel: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0                                                                                                                                                                                         
       version: 06                                                                                                                                                                                                               
       bits: 64 bits                                                                                                                                                                                                             
       horloge: 33MHz                                                                                                                                                                                                            
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom                                                                                                                                                 
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0                                                                                                                                                                                  
       ressources: irq:127 mémoire:e0000000-e0ffffff mémoire:d0000000-dfffffff portE/S:4000(taille=64)

$ sudo lspci -vv -k -s 00:02.0

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake Integrated Graphics
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 127
        Region 0: Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Region 4: I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
                        ExtTag- RBE+
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: fee0800c  Data: 4122
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] #1b
        Capabilities: [200 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
                ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
                ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
        Capabilities: [300 v1] #13
        Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
        Kernel modules: i915_bpo
```

For the last one:

```
$ sudo lshw -c display

  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)


$ sudo lspci -vv -k -s 00:02.0


00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake Integrated Graphics
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
        Region 0: Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Region 4: I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
                        ExtTag- RBE+
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] #1b
        Capabilities: [200 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
                ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
                ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
        Capabilities: [300 v1] #13
        Kernel modules: i915_bpo
```

Any idea how to make the last desktop working?